# MySQL: How to set default value if provded value is null

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my database table where the default needs to be 'int 0' but also null can be provided due to legacy.

I have attached a picture to show what I am trying to do.

The problem I am having is that when I untick 'Not Null' and have a default of 0, and a null value is provided then null is added.

But if I tick the box and null is provided it does not add 0, my code throws an exception instead stating the value for this column must not be null.

I want it do that if null is provided then it defaults to 0.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Note: I am using Datagrip

[image: Example]

I am assuming something in 'default expression' but I am not sure what

Comment: Only autoincremented numeric column assumes NULL value like "generate next". So you must use BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a BEFORE INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable BEFORE INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW 
   SET NEW.testfield = COALESCE(NEW.testfield, 0);
```

More information on triggers can be found in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check Data on controller before sending it to database

```
if(testfield == null) { tedtfield = 0;}
```

Comment: Hello, no I know this is the solution, but as we have legacy stuff many changes and checks would be needed for this as a permenant solution. But as a temporary/ permenant fix is what I am looking for in the DB if possible